# Ionic3 - How to send a data from HomePage to another ts file through ShareProvider

Tags: javascript, html, database, button, ionic3

I don't understand how to passe a click button data to another ts file by using a providers file.
So i want to control 4 share button by  from home.html, i'm trying to pass the data from the home.html -> home.ts -> Popovershare.ts 
I added a share button inside a square button thanks to a poppvers. 
And when i try to call the home function directly to popovers.ts "`constructor(here)`"  i got several errors.

```
This is my home.html

    <button icon-only  (click)="click(1)">
    <button icon-only  (click)="click(2)">
    <button icon-only  (click)="click(3)">
    <button icon-only  (click)="click(4)">

This is my home.ts
 click(myEvent) {

    this.indexNumber = myEvent

    let numbr_select

    if (this.indexNumber == 1) {
      numbr_select = 1
    }
    if (this.indexNumber == 2) {
      numbr_select = 2
    }
    if (this.indexNumber == 3) {
      numbr_select = 3
    }
    if (this.indexNumber == 4) {
      numbr_select = 4
    }
    }
    this.indexNumber =  numbr_select

     this.shareprovider.ValueFonction(this.indexNumber)

    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoversharePage, {

    }, {
      cssClass: 'csspopover'
    });
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
```

this is my shareprovider.ts

```
  template: `


      <ion-grid>
... share button with (click)="shareclick()"
      </ion-grid>

  constructor() {
    this.ValueFonction()
  }
  ValueFonction(Number_selected?: any) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
      if (Number_selected == i) {
        //    console.log(Number_selected, 'Valeur')
      }
    }
    return Number_selected
  }
```

And this is my Popovershare.ts

```
let i
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(1)
      alert(1)
      break;
    case 1:
      this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(2)
      alert(2)
      break;
    case 2:
      this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(3)
      alert(3)
      break;
    case 3:
      this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(4)
      alert(4)
      break;
  }
}
```

In these codes, it show in the console the number that i assigned for each button  but when i try to call from popovers.ts to shareprovider.ts  with this

```
this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(4)  all alert run at the same time, i don't understand why.
```

I just want to control the `shareclick()` but this button is in another file ts, hope you understand.

Thanks for your attention !

Comment: i found the solution: navparam